# Corrigir um Erro - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um curso de Programação JavaScript e não consigo resolver uma questão.

Segue o Enunciado.

**Declarar uma função chamada “mover”, que recebe dois arrays, remove o último elemento do primeiro e adiciona-o ao segundo.**

**Exemplo:**

```
var umArray = [1, 2, 3];

var outroArray = [4, 5];

mover(umArray, outroArray);

umArray //deveria ser [1, 2]

outroArray //deveria ser [4, 5, 3]
```

**Minha Resposta**

```
function mover (umArray,outroArray){

var umArray = [1, 2,3];

var outroArray = [4,5];

umArray.pop()

outroArray.push(2)

}
```

**Erros:**

A função mover([1,2],[3,4]) deve modificar a primeira matriz para que seu valor seja [1] e modifique a segunda para que seu valor seja [3,4,2]

Comment: Obrigado Luiz. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem alguns erros em sua função:

- Você redeclarou os parâmetros `umArray` e `outroArray` com valores fixos dentro da função:

```
    var umArray = [1, 2,3];
    var outroArray = [4,5];
```

Isso está incorreto, você recebe esses valores por parâmetro, portanto pode apagar isso.

- Você utilizou os métodos `push` e `pop`, correto, mas quando o método `pop` é utilizado, ele remove e retorna o valor, e esse valor que deveria ser utilizado como parâmetro no `push`, porém você não utilizou o retorno do `pop` e fixou o valor enviado ao `push`:

`outroArray.push(2)`

---

Veja um exemplo do seu código com as correções sugeridas:

```js
function mover (umArray,outroArray){
  const valor = umArray.pop();
  outroArray.push(valor);
}

var umArray = [1, 2, 3];
var outroArray = [4, 5];

mover(umArray, outroArray);

console.log(umArray); //deveria ser [1, 2]
console.log(outroArray); //deveria ser [4, 5, 3]
```

---

Como o método `pop` retorna o valor e é o valor que será enviado ao método `push`, você consegue fazer todo esse processo em apenas uma linha, utilizando o retorno do método `pop` como parâmetro no método `push`:

```js
function mover (umArray,outroArray){
  outroArray.push(umArray.pop());
}

var umArray = [1, 2, 3];
var outroArray = [4, 5];

mover(umArray, outroArray);

console.log(umArray); //deveria ser [1, 2]
console.log(outroArray); //deveria ser [4, 5, 3]
```

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Daniel, Muito obrigado, sua resposta me ajudou muito. Obrigado mesmo pela força.

Comment: Boa Noite Augusto, sou novo no Stackoverflow, não localizei o local para marcar a resolução que me foi apresentada pelo Daniel. Poderia me mostra o caminho por favor?

Comment: @AugustoVasques, obrigado